# How to schedule a .vbs script with UI elements?

Tags: authentication, vbscript, scheduling

I am new to vb scripting. I need to schedule a windows task which can run a vbs file.
The script opens up a application from its shortcut, feeds username and password and performs login.
In other words, I need to automate the restart process.
The scripts runs as expected when opened manually but scheduler cannot not run it.
I think the problem is with those UI elements(used for login).
Please suggest how to get through it.
Thank you!

Comment: Did you create the task with schtasks or with the windows gui? If in the gui did you chose "run only when user is logged on" ?

Comment: I used windows gui. It calls a batch which in turn calls the vbs file. Now the scheduling problem is solved in this way. But when the task is run, the application window does not come to the front. So the ui input values which i send through sendKeys don't get in and the login fails. Though I have used appActivate method, still the window does not come to front. Can you please suggest how to fix it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: But you chose "run only when user is logged on" in the gui not "run whether user is logged on or not" ? Is the application window completely invisible or minimized?

Comment: Thank you for the response. yes, I have chosen "run only when user is logged on". Application window opens but not on foreground. It blinks in the task bar. But could not come to front so that the credentials might go in the appropriate input boxes....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AppActivate does not itself restore the window if it is for some reason minimized.

You can try to find the reason why it's minimized (maybe it has something to do with the batch calling the vbs calling the application, I cannot really say) or you can try a little hack in the vbscript like the following:

After the AppActivate do a:

```
oShell.SendKeys "% r"
```

This is equivalent of  <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SpaceBar</kbd>, <kbd>r</kbd> so it opens the windows dialog for Maximize, Minimize, Restore options and choses "Restore".

Note that this might only be <kbd>r</kbd> on english copies of windows. If you use another Language manually open that menu by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SpaceBar</kbd> and looking what the actual hotkey on your system is (it would be underlined in the dialog). Afterwards replace the r in the script with whatever hotkey is used in your language.

Comment: Thank you, It works if I minimize all opened apps and then activate the required app. The only situation when it fails now is when I am not connected to desktop(It is a remote desktop). If I disconnected from the system, the script again fails as the application goes out of focus.